# Accessing your iPod library

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, media-player, avfoundation

I would like to access the file representing the song in your ipod library, so I can perform some calculations. Is there actually way of doing that as it seems I am not allowed to access the file when I get the AssetsURL property of the MPMediaItem object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you get back is not a file URL, but you can use it to create an AVAssetReader/AVAssetReaderTrackOutput pair that will let you read either the packet or LPCM data of the track.

Comment: sounds interesting, but I cannot test this at this time as my developer account expired and there is no iPod app on the simulator.. I will accept your answer as soon as I get down to actually testing this out